# Ruby/Selenium/Watir-Webdriver: "path is not absolute" error for absolute path

Tags: css, ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

```
document_name ='TestDoc'
document_path = ("/Users/Me/QA/Project/Documents/#{document_name}")

File.new ("/Users/Me/QA/Project/Documents/#{document_name}") # => File is created
filename_field.send_keys("#{document_path}")
filename_field.send_keys :tab # => To Trigger event but where error occurs
```

filename_field = browser.file_field(:name, 'file') declared in a module elsewhere.

As far as I can tell, I have provided an absolute path for the filename to upload the file but when the tab key is sent, an error occurs of:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: path is not absolute:
```

With an odd [squiggly symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5taT.png) in RubyMine that I've never seen before. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I added

```
puts filename_field.value 
# => C:\fakepath\TestDoc
```

Spoke to one of the developers and she said "Browser does it to fake things out, so the filesystem isn't exposed". Not sure if that helps solve my issue or I'm SOL?

Comment: I'm confused.  You're using `send_keys` on the `filename_field` var before you've declared it.

Comment: Sorry, that was declared elsewhere and didn't mean to include it in the code snippet. Will edit!

Comment: Given the output of `filename_field.value`, is it correct to assume that you are using Windows?

Comment: @JustinKo I am using OSX. I believe that output is faked for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error comes from Chromedriver, and comes from sending an incorrect path string to a file element. Since `:tab` is not a path, it is correctly raising an error.

You shouldn't need to send a tab; just sending the path of the file should accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I was barking up the wrong tree here. The idea behind the :tab was to try and trigger the event that actually brings the file that's being uploaded into the UI rather than just setting the file_field and nothing happening like I am getting currently. This gives me something to go on though and resolves this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see many small strange things in your code.

Why

```
document_path = ("/Users/Me/QA/Project/Documents/#{document_name}")
```

Not

```
document_path = "/Users/Me/QA/Project/Documents/#{document_name}"
```

Why

```
filename_field.send_keys("#{document_path}")
```

Not

```
filename_field.send_keys(document_path)
```

But the main question is why you are using **send_keys** instead of **set**?

I failed to reproduce your problem. Maybe it will be possible if you will provide your html. But i suggest you to try:

```
filename_field.set(document_path)
```

Because you can easily check it even with irb send_keys is acting differently in firefox and in chrome for example. So maybe problem with it.

**Another suggestion**

That is a much more weak idea. But...

Try to clear value before changing it. You can do it with javascript:

```
b.execute_script("arguments[0].value=''", field)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm still fairly new to this and self-taught so your comments are helpful! I had actually been switching between set and send_keys with the same result, it just so happened I was using send_keys as I created this post.  
I tried using the clear field javascript and also testing in Firefox using IRB. I got the following error when trying to set the field in FF:  
`code Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055`

Comment: `set` just does a `clear` before doing `send_keys` so `send_keys` might be the preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Chromedriver 2.26.436421 and it was solved when I removed the code which was sending the tab key.

With previous Chromedriver sending tab key was required to trigger the change event on the file input but with latest one it seems like it is only causing issues and the change event gets triggered without it.